# Java does not seem to accept Romance as timezone alias. What should it be?

Tags: java, datetime, groovy, timezone

I'm trying to convert a date string from another application in Groovy. Something like
"18-sep-2009 10:25:11 Romance Daylight Time"

It looks like Java does not understand the Romance as timezone alias. "18-sep-2009 10:25:11 Pacific Daylight Time" works fine.

Is there a fix for this other than parse the string and replace "Romance Daylight Time" with the something Java understands? If not, what should it be instead for Europe/Paris timezone?

Comment: There is no "Romance" with java. Not anymore :-((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try "Central European Time." That's the output of this short program:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris");
        System.out.println(tz.getDisplayName());
    }
}
```

(I feel almost obliged to suggest using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), but I'm not sure there's enough evidence to suggest it in this case other than on general principle, so I'll just leave this parenthetical comment...)

Comment: this works. Thanks! will have to take a look at Joda soon as it has been recommended by number of people!

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:** There are two things that need to be addressed:

1. Change the Date-Time string to have the [standard name of the timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) which is `Europe/Paris`.
2. Build a case-insensitive parser using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "18-sep-2009 10:25:11 Europe/Paris";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                    .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                    .appendPattern("dd-MMM-uuuu HH:mm:ss zzzz")
                                    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2009-09-18T10:25:11+02:00[Europe/Paris]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/S5qo68)

However, if changing the Date-Time string is not in your control i.e. you want to go with `Romance Daylight Time` itself, `java.time` provides you with a clean way to handle it. All you need to prepare before using `java.time` API is a `Map` with all such non-standard timezone names.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "18-sep-2009 10:25:11 Romance Daylight Time";
        Map<String, String> zoneIdMap = Map.of("Romance Daylight Time", "Europe/Paris");

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                    .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                    .appendPattern("dd-MMM-uuuu HH:mm:ss")
                                    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDateTime.from(dtf.parse(strDateTime, new ParsePosition(0)))
                                .atZone(ZoneId.of("Romance Daylight Time", zoneIdMap));
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2009-09-18T10:25:11+02:00[Europe/Paris]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/dLueE8)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>